# Design preview blur in Latest Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Recently I updated my Android Studio and when I started to
continue my old project the XML design in every  is very blurry
and it is like if there is a circle then the border of the circle is not
smooth its like zig-zag type like given in the image.
So what should I do about that,

I just use relative layout in XML not Constraint View

I also try with a fresh installation of Android Studio + SDK

[image]